# CreateProcessAsUser - Create process with a different parent?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, uac, createprocessasuser

I was reading about UAC's implementation on MSDN: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx

Chanced upon this interesting line:

> Although AIS is technically the parent of the elevated process, AIS
>   uses new support in the CreateProcessAsUser API that sets the
>   process’s parent process ID to that of the process that originally
>   launched it (see Figure 13).

Here is the MSDN page for CreateProcessAsUser:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcessAsUser(
  _In_opt_     HANDLE hToken,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  _Inout_opt_  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  _In_         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  _In_         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  _Out_        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

The exert says we can create a process and set a different parent by using options in the API. I am not sure how to do this? Do I need to dig into the token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is documented in the MSDN entries for the [InitializeProcThreadAttributeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683481(v=vs.85).aspx) and [UpdateProcThreadAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686880(v=vs.85).aspx) functions.

In particular see the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS` attribute:

> The lpValue parameter is a pointer to a handle to a process to use instead of the calling process as the parent for the process being created. The process to use must have the PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS access right.